# How to write HtmlHelper in Fluent syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, fluent

I have a simple tag builder that looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Tag(this HtmlHelper helper, string tag, string content)
{
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(tag){InnerHtml = content};
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.NormalTag));
}
```

And, I can use it like this:

```
@Html.Tag("em", Model.Title)
```

which produces:

```
<em>The Title</em>
```

How can this be written to use a Fluent Syntax so it's use would look like this:

```
@Html.Tag("em").Content(Model.Title)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this over regular HTML? Generally this type of thing is not recommended since any developer coming on to the project (who probably already knows HTML) will now have to learn your wrapper for it. It also makes writing HTML more verbose and less readable.

Comment: The benefit I am hoping to achieve is to abstract the HTML as much as possible (for the benefit of the C# centric developer, not the HTML developer).  My goal is not necessarily for a simple scenario like this, but in developing more complex Html builders that have a number of moving parts that would benefit from the Fluent syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to define a builder interface and implementation. I hope my example can provide some guidance:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static IMyTagBuilder Tag(this HtmlHelper helper, string tag)
    {
        return new MyTagBuilder(tag);
    }
}
```

Then you define your builder interface and implementation:

```
public interface IMyTagBuilder : IHtmlString
{
    IHtmlString Content(string content);
}

public class MyTagBuilder : IMyTagBuilder
{
    private readonly TagBuilder _tagBuilder;

    public MyTagBuilder(string tag)
    {
        _tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(tag);
    }

    public IHtmlString Content(string content)
    {
        _tagBuilder.InnerHtml = content;
        return this;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return _tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.NormalTag);
    }
}
```

Since `IMyTagBuilder` implements `IHtmlString`, it can be used either with or without calling `.Content()` afterwards.

A great trick to use when implementing fluent interfaces it to use a [`IFluentInterface`](https://github.com/kzu/IFluentInterface) to hide object members (`ToString`, `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `GetType`) from IntelliSense, it removes some noise.

**EDIT**: A great resource for building fluent APIs is Daniel Cazzulino's screencast from building Funq [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi9K9N9KtEc&index=8&list=PLpBzqAJhzCLfPHtdcPEy1jj3W16MAeX1M)

Comment: +1 - this looks like it would work, although you may want to store a reference to the original HTML helper object in the tag builder for later access (as it contains a great deal of useful information).

Comment: @TimMedora Absolutely, but in this example it wasn't needed :)

Comment: Added a link to an awesome video about fluent APIs

Comment: I'd upvote your answer multiple times if I could, your explanation is crystal clear and really helped me in my project.