# asp.net-mvc - creating html helper extension to pass view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This may be a bit moot, but it is something I want to do just for the sake of seeing how, and I think it is a little cleaner than the typical method.

Right now, I can pass extra `ViewData` to a partial view like this;

```
@Html.Partial( "path/to/partial", new ViewDataDictionary{{ "key", "value" }})
```

And that works fine, though I was wondering, would it be possible to make an extension method that would just clean it up a bit? I've tried to do it for a few hours now and am finding myself a bit lost, but I am attempting to go the route of ..

```
@Html.Partial( "path/to/partial" ).With("key","data").With("key2","data2")
```

So basically, it's just syntax sugar. But I haven't been able to get this to work. Has anyone else achieved something similar?

## Update

I actually may have solved this myself. I had to turn the idea upside down to get the result I want. I'm not sure if I'll even use it, given how obtuse it is, but it was interesting to learn about! I am very welcoming to any insight that could be used to make this better. But essentially, the trick was to do it in reverse.

```
using System;
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html {
    public static partial class PartialViewExtensions {
        /// <summary>
        /// An Html Helper specifically for rendering a partial view with a fluently declared ViewDataDictionary.
        /// </summary>
        public class PartialHtmlHelper : HtmlHelper
        {
            public PartialHtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) 
                : base(viewContext, viewDataContainer) { }  
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepare the upcoming partial view with view data.
        /// </summary>
        public static PartialHtmlHelper With( this HtmlHelper helper, string key, dynamic value ) {
            var partial = new PartialHtmlHelper( helper.ViewContext, helper.ViewDataContainer );
            partial.ViewData.Add( key, value );
            return partial;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prepare the upcoming partial view with view data.
        /// </summary>
        public static PartialHtmlHelper With( this PartialHtmlHelper helper, string key, dynamic value ) {
            helper.ViewData.Add( key, value ); return helper;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render a prepared partial view with readied view data.
        /// </summary>
        public static MvcHtmlString Using( this PartialHtmlHelper helper, string partialViewName ) {
            return helper.Partial( partialViewName, helper.ViewData );
        }
    }
}
```

And that makes it very easy to declare with fluent, chained methods.

```
@Html
   .With("alpha", "alpha.property" )
   .With("beta", "beta.property" )
   .With("gamma", "gamma.property")
   .With("epsilon", DateTime.UtcNow() )
   .With("sigma", "sigma.property" )
   .Using("Templates/Form/Slots")
```

Comment: Yeah, that is my goal. I essentially would love to declare each item in the dictionary as a chain of extensions, and then the whole thing gets rendered as if I had done it the original way. I know it sounds silly, but it is just the kind of way I like to code. If I'm going to use the helpers, I at least want them to feel fluent.

Comment: Show us the code for your `With()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any code for the `With` method yet. I'm still stuck trying to figure out what to attach it to. I thought attaching it to `MvcHtmlString` would work, but that doesn't seem to behave like I thought.

Comment: The problem is, the `MvcHtmlString` class hierarchy doesn't contain much functionality that will help you here (all it appears to do is give you a `ToHtmlString()` method). You might be better off writing your own `Partial()` extension method, wrapping one of the existing `Partial()` methods.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669904/how-to-write-htmlhelper-in-fluent-syntax) about creating fluent html helpers may help

Comment: Hey, wow @StephenMuecke, thanks a lot. I think that actually will be pretty useful. I put the conclusion I came to up above, hoping that someone might see it and be able to show me a smarter way to do it. But I'll pursue this lead you just linked too. This is mostly useful for situations where I need to pass more than one or two things to the partial view, and it just gets kind of crowded in the HTML if I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence `Html.Partial` is an extension method so you can't add an extension method to an extension method.

Comment: You're right. So I just turned it upside down. I added the answer I came to up above, just now. I'm not sure if it really serves any useful purpose, but it was an interesting thing to dig into.